# How to read columns from CSV file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

```
def rowfilter():
    field_data = {}
    try:
        csv_read = csv.reader(open('sample.csv', ), delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        for row in csv_read:
            for field in row[7]:
                print(field)       


    except FileNotFoundError:
            print("File not found")

rowfilter()
```

This code runs successfully but I want this code to print data prior to the user_input.
e.g. if user enter 5 then its should print all the details from 1 to 5, along with all the column associated with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def rowfilter(col1, col2):

    try:
        csv_read = csv.reader(open('items.csv'), delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        for row in csv_read:
        print(row[int(cols[0]):int(cols[1])])  

    except FileNotFoundError:
            print("File not found")

inputrows = input("Enter columns in the format: col1 col2 ")
rowfilter(inputrows.split()))
```

I have edited this answer as per your comment, it is possible to treat the csv row as a list once the csv reader has read it. Therefore this method will print columns from col1 to col2. Note that python is 0 indexed.

Comment: how to read particular/specific  column for user_input from table. e.g I need all the columns for hows row value starts from 3 to n..

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly a job for [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', delimiter=',', quotechar='|')

#you can get the 7th column like this
df_seven = df[df.columns[7]]

#Then slice the dataframe as you see fit
df_seven[0:5] # first five rows
df_seven[4:9] # rows 4 to 9... etc
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me in python3.5